# Yarn, What is the meaning of "unmet peer dependencies"

Tags: yarnpkg

my package.json is

```
"peerDependencies": {
    "vue": "^2.6.10",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10",
    "webpack": "^4.41.2"
}
```

and when I try 'yarn install'

```
warning " > sass-loader@8.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.36.0".
warning "@nuxtjs/vuetify > vuetify-loader@1.4.2" has unmet peer dependency "vue-template-compiler@^2.5.0".
warning "@nuxtjs/vuetify > vuetify-loader@1.4.2" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^4.0.0".
warning "@nuxtjs/vuetify > vuetify@2.1.12" has unmet peer dependency "vue@^2.6.4".
warning " > ant-design-vue@1.4.7" has unmet peer dependency "vue@>=2.6.6".
warning " > ant-design-vue@1.4.7" has unmet peer dependency "vue-template-compiler@>=2.6.6".
warning "ant-design-vue > @ant-design/icons-vue@2.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "vue@>=2.5.0".
warning "ant-design-vue > @ant-design/icons-vue@2.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "vue-template-compiler@>=2.5.0".
```

this means, I have to install below

```
"webpack@^4.36.0".
"webpack@^4.0.0".
"vue@^2.6.4".
"vue@>=2.6.6".
"vue@>=2.5.0".
"vue-template-compiler@^2.5.0".
"vue-template-compiler@>=2.6.6".
"vue-template-compiler@>=2.5.0".
```

As you know, I already include webpack, vue, vue-template-compiler in package.json, and they are  recent version.

".. unmet peer dependencies .." means we have to install exact version of the package?
If so, how do I install different version of same package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you using `peerDependencies` in your project?

Based on your question I think that is not intended: those dependencies (vue, vue-template-compiler and webpack) should be in the `dependencies` or `devDependencies` of your `package.json`. Adding it to the `peerDependencies` will not install them when you run `yarn install`.

So to solve your current situation:

- add the dependencies your project needs in the `dependencies` or `devDependencies` (does not really matter if you're not working on a library to be consumed by other projects)
- run `yarn install`
- if you get the peerDependencies warning, run `yarn add ASKED_LIBRARIES`. This warning happens when you install a library that requires that a specific library is installed in your project.